# Django - Unable to get values from input field

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm currently working on a Django project where I am trying to retrieve values from HTML input fields when a submit button is clicked. One is plane text and two are datetime fields. The view that is called runs when the button is clicked (I've hard coded values within my view function to test) but when I print the values of the input fields I'm trying to retrieve I get `None` for all three.

The form I'm using in my html template looks like so:

```
<form action="{% url 'get-billing'%}" method='GET'>
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" value="click" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm fs-6">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

views.py:

```
def get_billing(request):

    url='placeholder for api url'
    secret='placeholder for api key'

    client = request.GET.get('client-name')
    start = request.GET.get('start-date')
    end = request.GET.get('end-date')

    print(client)
    print(start)
    print(end)

    response = requests.get(url, headers={
        'key': secret,
        'start': '2021/10/01',
        'end': '2021/10/02',
    }).json()

    # print(request)


    context = {'data':response}

    return render(request, 'billing/billing.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
path('get_billing',views.get_billing, name='get-billing'),
```

And this is what the 3 print statements return even though there are values in all 3.

```
None
None
None
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post the form. Your form so far is empty so there is no input at all.

Comment: Add the relevant input tags like this `<input type="text" name="client-name" required>`

Comment: Thanks for your responses Synthase & Ayodele Ademosu. I eventually go this working. I was playing around with the form while I was busy testing. At one point I commented out the beginning form tag and added it a couple of lines before this (To include the inputs which I hadn't done). For some reason the commented out code was preventing this from working. The minute I removed the commented out form tag it worked as expected. Not sure why this happened if the code was commented out but its working now. Thanks again for your inputs, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,i was checking again your code now. It is not working for the simple reason there is not the input field into the form into your html page. You must put the input with the names 'client-name','start-date','end-date' within the opening and the closing of the form